# Error uploading image to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, ionic3

I'm making an app with Ionic where i want the user to pick an image, crop it and upload it. For this I'm using the [cordova camera plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/) and the [cordova crop plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crop). This is my code for the file picker:

```
OpenFilePicker() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: 0  //0 = Chose File; 1 = Take picture
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      //Using the crop plugin:
     this.crop.crop(imageData, {quality: 75})
     .then((newPath) => {
      //Creating the blob
      this.blobimg = new Blob([newPath], {type : 'image/jpeg'});
     })
     .catch((err) => {
     // Handle error crop plugin
     })
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error camera plugin
    });
  }
```

And then i upload the blob created to the firebase Storage:

```
[...]
const imageRef = storageRef.child(`profilePics/photo.jpg`).put(this.blobimg);
```

It says it's successful but the image uploaded is only 105 B and is all black (that is, it's not really an image).

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue, so it may be possible that the blob is not being created fully or is incomplete - I'm still looking into it so will get back to you on this once I've found a solution

Ok I have cracked it!!, You need to use canvas to convert the image into base64 then upload it to firebase as a data_url, the code is below, written in vuejs but I'm sure you can refactor.

```
photoUpload: function () {
  var img = new Image()
  var c = document.createElement('canvas')
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
  let storage = firebase.storage()
  let storageRef = storage.ref()
  let filesRef = storageRef.child('images/' + this.photo)
  // window.alert(img.src)
  img.onload = function () {
    c.width = this.naturalWidth     // update canvas size to match image
    c.height = this.naturalHeight
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0)
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.75)
    filesRef.putString(dataURL, 'data_url')
    .then((snapshot) => {
      window.alert('Uploaded a blob or file!')
      var downloadURL = snapshot.downloadURL
      window.alert(downloadURL)
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }
  img.crossOrigin = ''             // if from different origin
  img.src = this.photoURL
},
```